# Installation and Upgrade of TeX Live has issues

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

If you have manually installed the latest TeX Live like this (installing as `root` user):

```
wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xvzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl-*
perl ./install-tl
```

you may get errors when attempting to update.

Running `tlmgr update --all` (as a non-`root` user), there are errors about `cannot write to directory`.

Using `root` (or `sudo tlmgr update --all`), the errors are of the form

```
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2022). Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

or `bash: tlmgr: command not found`.

How do you fix these issues?

Should you run the `update-tlmgr-latest` thing from above?

Answer (score 1):

As an ordinary user, you should not be able to write to the system-wide install of TeX Live, so getting that error is both good and correct. You should be using either a specific system user (e.g. `texlive`), or the superuser `root`. Using `sudo` to run it is the same as using `root`, and will work (but if you have used a system user for the initial install, you should only use that user, not `root`).

If `tlmgr` is not found, you need to add the path to the `tlmgr` executable to `root`'s path:

Run `sudo su - ; nano ~/.bashrc` (assuming you use `bash` as your shell). Add a line similar to the following, then save and exit.

`export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/linux-x86_64/:${PATH}`

If you get the `cross version error`, the fix is the same: add the correct path to the front of `root`'s path, and it will choose that one.

### Why is there a version you didn't install, though?

Generally, it will be a version installed by a package manager to meet a dependency of something you have installed. This may be something as simple as an editor which has TeX mode (the editor `Kile` fits this description).

### Can the old TeX Live be removed?

Probably, yes. But DO NOT use `rm` to delete it. That will cause more problems than it solves. Use the package manager, that's what it is for. It may attempt to remove some things which you want, though, so pay attention to the list of things which will be removed.

If you are on Debian Linux, there are some very nice [instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla) for convincing your package manager (`apt`, `apper`, `synaptic`) that you have TeX Live, so that it won't try to install an outdated version again. You may be able to convince RPM (`yum`, `dnf`) of the same on RedHat based distros, but the exact process is different, and is not covered by that link. Someone on [unix&linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) may be able to help you with that, but is outside the scope of this site.

### Updating releases (e.g. from 2022 to 2023):

One of the errors above specifies running `update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update`. If you copy that command, and run it, it won't work. If you are on Windows, you would use `update-tlmgr-latest.exe --update`, and it should work. If you are on Linux, use `update-tlmgr-latest.sh --update`. The error isn't particularly clear, but it is also assuming some familiarity with file extensions and executable formats for various systems. I don't have any suggestion for a better error message, in case anyone who can fix it is reading this.

Personally, I would not update the version using `update-tlmgr-latest`. Instead, I would install a new version, either leaving the existing version in place, or removing it once I am happy that the new version is working with my documents.

### Installing using a system user:

Above, there was mention of using a system-user, not `root` to install the TeX Live system. Here's how to do that:

Using `root` or `sudo`, create a new system user named `texlive` using the following command (or something substantially similar):

```
useradd -d /usr/local/texlive -m -r texlive
passwd -l texlive
```

This will create a system user (`-r`), with a home directory of `/usr/local/texlive` (`-d /usr/local/texlive -m`), and lock the password (so there is no password which can log in to the account). Use `sudo su - texlive` to change to the `texlive` user, then run the install as listed in the question.

The main reason for this is separation of responsibility. The `texlive` user is used for nothing more or less than the administration of the TeX Live install. It can't be used for any other system administration, and it is very clear which files are part of the TeX Live install (they are owned by `texlive`, not `root`).

### Advanced topic - Multiple versions of TeX Live working together:

(automatic version works on Linux, may or may not work on Mac, will not work on Windows)

Good News! It is possible to install multiple different releases of Tex Live, without them interfering with each other. Install each one in a separate directory, such as `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/`.

For choosing between versions, you can manually change your `PATH` variable, or you can make the computer do that automatically for you. To make the computer do it, you can use the `environment-modules` package, with a module file similar to this (create one for each version of TeX Live you have installed):

```
#%Module1.0#######################################################################
#
#
module-whatis   "Loads settings for the TeXLive 2023"
prepend-path    PATH            /usr/local/tex/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux
prepend-path    MANPATH         /usr/local/tex/texlive/2023/texmf/doc/man
prepend-path    INFOPATH        /usr/local/tex/texlive/2023/texmf/doc/info
```

If you have one such module file for each version, you can easily select a version using `module load texlive/2023`, and revert back to default with `module remove texlive/2023`. Again, for specific help on using module files in this manner, [unix&linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) is a good place to ask for help (after looking at the man pages, of course).