# how to intall Miktex for windows 8 64 bite

Tags: miktex, overleaf

I'm trying to install Latex so i understand that i need to install MikTex first
then install Texmaker or TeXstudio so try all version of Miktex but in install they gives
" MikTex requires windows 10 (or greater)"
i used overleaf but they cause problem (need upgrade ) because they can't compile all my reprt thesis.

Comment: Off-topic: [Windows 8 has reached end of life at 2016-01-12.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-8). [Windows 8.1 has reached end of life at 2023-01-10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-81). So you should not use it at any computer connected to the internet! Ignoring this would endanger not only yourself but also others.

Answer (score 3):

[TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/) is the most widely used distribution of TeX with support for the widest variety of platforms: [instructions for installing on Windows](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html).

Platform-specific notes:

- Windows uses a graphical installer by default;
- the instructions imply the Windows installer installs as your ordinary user by default;
- includes `perl`;
- there are some comments concerning security risks specific to this platform on the linked page.

TeX Live-specific points:

- TeX Live is the basis for Overleaf, so if you've been using Overleaf, this will be more similar than MikTeX;
- unlike MikTeX, TeX Live includes an installation of `perl` on Windows;
- there is no on-the-fly installation of packages.

Unless you are extremely short of either disk space or bandwidth, I would recommend installing everything (`comprehensive` scheme). That way, you will not continually get errors complaining about packages you don't have, which is likely to be extremely frustrating. Of course, this is a matter of personal preference, but it is fair to say this is what most people do. It also means you won't be stuck without a needed package if you need to work offline and will not have to rely on the net for documentation. If your internet provider is anything like mine, this, in itself, is reason enough not to cut corners. (And on campus it is even worse.)

If you install piecemeal, note that you may end up with conflicting versions of packages unless you ensure you update your existing packages at the same time. This is another point against this approach. It's always best to avoid updating before an important deadline and I wouldn't want to be choosing between doing without a needed package and risking conflicts. In the past, this would probably not have affected core functionality. But if you use LaTeX, ongoing development means that's no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that MiKTex is not able to be run on your system. You can't get around this, so you can't install MikTeX. However, MikTeX is not the only way to get LaTeX (and associated programs). The distribution of LaTeX I am most familiar with for Windows (other than MiKTeX) is TeXLive. There are [instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html) for how to install TeXLive for Windows.

Assumptions for the following paragraphs (if these assumptions don't apply to you, please use the answer provided by cfr instead of this one):

- You have reliable internet
- The internet is not the fastest (low bandwidth)
- You can trouble-shoot technical problems easily
- To start with, you only need the basics (only a few additional packages), and are happy to get others as and when you need them
- You are using Windows (of some version)

For my use-case (which is not exactly typical, a fact which I often forget), a minimal install with additional downloads was fine. This is not always the case for everyone. For me, the comprehensive install was going to take about 5 or 6 hours. The minimal plus specifically chosen packages was about one and a half hours.

In general, I recommend not installing for all users (again, this is for Windows - see other links below for other systems), but just installing it using your own user account. For me, I didn't install the default (comprehensive, but not complete) set of packages: I knew I probably wouldn't need all of them, and it would take quite some time to download and install the whole set. I started with a minimal install, and got the additional packages I needed after.

Unlike MikTeX, TeXLive doesn't do 'on-the-fly' downloads of things you have included, so you will need to run `tlmgr` to get packages if you get errors about packages not being present, and re-compile once the packages are installed.

By default, the editor `TeXworks` is installed as part of TeXLive (Windows only - other systems may have different editors, or no editor at all, installed). You can use this editor, or are free to get another if you prefer, including `TeXMaker` or `TexStudio`.

For those who stumble upon this question, and don't use Windows, there should be specific instructions on the TeXLive site if TeXLive is available for that system. This site also has questions and answers for other systems: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676877) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678710/). Searching this site for [install texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=install+texlive) will also get some answers for that.

---

EDIT (in response to comments)
My original answer suggested a minimal install, which, it has been pointed out, is not optimal for most users in most circumstances.

If you go for a minimal install, follow it up with an almost immediate install of packages you are likely to need, and don't get ones you don't. For example, don't get "all the fonts" unless you are making posters. But do get `babel` if you are not working in English.

Also, do an update of everything you have before you install new packages (to avoid version-based problems).

Comment: Thanks you for all response i trying to install texliv and i want to choose the option not complete but i can't find this word . the two option that appear to me it is " Install"  and the second "Unpack only" is it option not complete is the "Unpack  only"

Comment: @k.k It's been a while since I installed it, so I can't offer any real advice here. What I can suggest is following @cfr's answer, and installing most (or all) of TeXLive. So, from the choice you have, click `Install`.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: @cfr Thank you again, for advice on making my answer better than it was. I have made some changes, to specify this applies to Windows, and make sure I don't give bad information.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your patience. I've tidied up the comments a bit, so you might want to do the same.

Comment: @cfr and @enkorvaks  I have install TeXLive and then i have intall Texmaker. So i test with tex file example and it gives me this error  " ! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package "     and unsertand how and  where i install this package

Comment: @k.k That's not a complaint about a package. It's a complaint from the package `minted` which requires some external stuff (i.e. non-TeX stuff) to work. See the manual for `minted` for details. You need to install Python (2.6 or later), if you don't have it, and Pygments, if it isn't included with Python. How to do this depends on your OS. For Windows, you probably need to look at the website (link in `minted`'s docs) and download something because you don't have the kind of access to software provided by Linux distros.

Comment: @crf thank you !